# Transferring database from Xampp to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xampp

I have a database dump from Xampp MySql server, and I need to transfer the full database of (200mb) to Sql Server 2014. Can somebody explain to me how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to migrate database from XAMPP to SQL Server:

1. Download and install ODBC driver for MySQL XAMPP.
2. Create System DNS of concerned XAMPP database by using ODBC connector.
3. Create a link server in SQL Server using that System DNS.
4. Create all required table schema in SQL Server.
5. Insert data into SQL Server Table by using INSERT INTO command, like below:

   ```
   INSERT INTO TargetTable (Col1, Col2, Col3,.....,Coln)
   Select Col1, Col2, Col3,.....,Coln
   from Openquery(linkServerName, 'Select Col1, Col2, Col3,.....,Coln from SourceTable');
   ```

I hope, these steps may help you. :)